# undefined is not an object (evaluating Promise .then)

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

Im getting this error while developing react native mobile application.

`fetchDB` function will return a promise

```
 fetchDB(key) {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem(key, result => {
        return result;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

fetching value from returned promise by using `.then()`

```
  getUserName = () => {
    var user = Storage.fetchDB("username");
    user.then(res => {
      alert(res);
    });
  };
```

its  rendering  the red screen with error

> undefined is not an object

Comment: `AsyncStorage.getItem` is asynchronous? anyway, a return value inside a callback function doesn't mean you're returning something from `fetchDB` function ... so you have two issues ... understanding asynchronous code, and understanding that your function doesn't actually return anything anyway ... try simply `return AsyncStorage.getItem(key);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** You need to return the promise function explicitly. Fail situation could be handled within catch callback:

```
fetchDB(key) {
 return AsyncStorage.getItem(key).catch(error => console.log(error));
}

fetchDB("username").then(res => alert(res));
```

**2)** Point (1) works only if `AsyncStorage.getItem` really returns promise. If it's not true, then you need to update `AsyncStorage.getItem` method to be promise-based. If you have not access to that method or don't want to touch it, the issue could be done also via updating `fetchDB` function in a way like:

```
fetchDB(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      AsyncStorage.getItem(key, resolve);
    } 
    catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    }
  })
}

fetchDB("username")
  .then(res => alert(res))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

**3)** I would even say that you don't need try-catch due to es6 Promises nature:

```
fetchDB(key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    AsyncStorage.getItem(key, resolve)
  )
}

fetchDB("username")
  .then(res => alert(res))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

That last `.catch` handles any errors thrown from `fetchDB` Promise.

Comment: As method returns promise without fail,,  Point(1) works perfectly. Tq